# Howto modify Sandcastle presentation style without changing the default installation files

Tags: documentation, build, sandcastle, shfb

My project uses Sandcastle and Sandcastle Help File Builder to generate documentation.

We're using a customized version of script_manifold.js that persists the user's language preference across pages (the default version resets the language preference with each page).

Currently, the script is located in the Sandcastle\presentation\VS2005\scripts folder.

Is there a way to override this script with a custom version, without having to mess with the Sandcastle installation? That is, can I have a file that is checked into source control along with my source code, and somehow have that file used by SHFB instead of the default Sandcastle one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never mind, I found the answer!

In the SHFB project explorer window, you can just create a folder with the same name as the presentation style content you wish to override. This works with any stock content, such as HTML, CSS or JS files. So in my situation, I needed to override the script_manifold.js file which lives in the Scripts folder of the VS2005 presentation style.

So I needed to create a folder called Scripts in my SHFB project, then put my script_manifold.js in that folder.

It all works perfectly. Excellent!